# how to make gvim hold terminal until it ends?

Tags: vim, find, xargs

I am trying to find and replace over file hierarchy using gvim like this:

```
  find . | xargs grep -l pattern | xargs -n 1 gvim -c "%s/pattern/replacement/gc" -c "wq"
```

I could probably try to make it work properly without the n flag, but I could have theoretically many, many files with matches. What happens now is that gvim dettaches from terminal, so xargs starts all instances of gvim one after another with little delay. If I could force gvim to hold terminal, xargs would wait for gvim to finish, thus there would ever only be one instance of gvim running.

Unfortunately I can't use vim in the environment that this is relevant to. I obtained a working binary for gvim from a colleague, but they did not have a vim binary and I failed to compile vim myself and gave up on it for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `-f` command-line option:

> ```
> -f        GUI: Do not disconnect from the program that started Vim.
>           'f' stands for "foreground".  If omitted, the GUI forks a new
>           process and exits the current one.  "-f" should be used when
>           gvim is started by a program that will wait for the edit
>           session to finish (e.g., mail or readnews).  If you want gvim
>           never to fork, include 'f' in 'guioptions' in your |gvimrc|.
> ```